# Laravel 5.2 : Validation issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In My controller :

```
$this->validate($request, [ 
     'name' => 'required',
]);

$tasks = new Task;

$tasks->name = $request->todo;
if($tasks->save()){
  $tasks->save();
  return back();
}
```

The field is filled and the issue is that the validator still throws error:
`The name field is required`.

Am i missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator validates REQUEST input, not your model. If you have a field in your request called `todo` and you want to make it required, you would do:

```
$this->validate($request, [ 
     'todo' => 'required', // this is the name of the field from your form as it comes through to the Request object
]);

$task = new Task();
$task->name = $request->todo;

if($task->save()) { // note, you don't need to call save() twice
    return back();
}

// you probably want to do something here in case save fails?
```

Comment: Oops My bad, I forgot that. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `'name' => 'required'` to `'todo' => 'required'`, because here you need to specify the name which wrote in the **FORM FIELD**

If you have used `<input type="text" name"todo" />` then in while defining the **RULES** in controller you need use "todo" just as follows:

```
    $this->validate($request, [ 
     'todo' => 'required', 
    ]);
```

Hope this helps you.